# Qt "Creating SSL context" error in few computers

Tags: c++, qt, ssl

I have this "Error creating SSL context" in a C++ application based on Qt.
I've put these DLL in the application directory and in "C:\Windows\system32":
    - libeay32.dll
    - libssl32.dll
    - ssleay32.dll
But still have the problem. It's weird because the application still works on  allmost all the systems.

Idees?

Comment: MSVCRT90.dll relies on side-by-side assembly mechanism (thus needs a proper .manifest file); to make an xcopiable distro with OpenSSL, you have to open the ssl dll-s in a hex editor, find the xml manifest there (will be plain text), then look for the MSVCRT version there; after that, find the respective MSVCRT90.dll in your c:/windows/ (searching for the version string -- if it works on your dev. machine, it is installed), then copy that, and a manifest (renamed to MICROSOFT.VC90.CRT) alongside the SSL dll-s. That's it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Creating SSL Context - Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894056/error-creating-ssl-context-qt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All computers need to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package ([Download here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en)).
After installation, all works!

Comment: There are three ways to install the MSVC2008SP1 Redist Package: (1) merge modules, (2) run the installer that Xavier links, or (3) include the required DLLs side-by-side with your exe. I'm currently getting this error, and so far including the atl, msvcr, msvcm, and msvcp libraries has not resolved the problem, although I was expecting that msvcr by itself should have worked. I'm still investigating. Anyone have an answer?

Comment: Here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894056/error-creating-ssl-context-qt/18917240#18917240

Comment: @AndrewS Note, 1) there are *different* MSVCRT90.dll versons floating around (and you need a match for what SSL libs require), and B) the thing needs a .manifest (see the comment below the OP's question).