# Error Creating SSL Context - Qt

Tags: c++, qt, openssl

I tried everything mentioned in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511767/qt-creating-ssl-context-error-in-few-computers)

but nothing worked.
  The binary works fine on Windows 64-bit, but almost always shows the error

```
Error Creating SSL Context()
```

on Windows 32-bit. I tried the demo http client example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At last, I found the solution. I was downloading dll's from  a dll website. You need to take these libraries

```
- libeay32.dll
- libssl32.dll
- ssleay32.dll
```

from this website [here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.2 file for 32 bit if you are using MSVC++ compiler

After installation of the above binary, copy the above three dll's in the the directory containing your binary file.

Comment: I have the same problem. By copying those files in the .exe directory, it works for a 32bits application but not for a 64bits one. How to solve that?

Comment: And I don't have libssl32.dll but a libssl.dll which is not in Qt installation folder like the two other files.

Comment: @SteveTJS you need to download the dlls from the link provided. The ones provided with qt won't work.

Comment: I tried this and all other suggestions here and in the other question referred above but nothing... *nada*... Any other ideas to overcome this?

Answer (score 11):

This error happens if:

- The `libeay32.dll` file and/or `ssleay32.dll` file is missing (and you need to place them beside your App's executable).
- Or, if `libeay32.dll` and/or `ssleay32.dll` are not compatible with your App.

I recommend [this](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) source for OpenSSL Windows binaries. These binaries have no external dependencies and tested with 32-bit and 64-bit Qt5.

**Update**: OpenSSL 1.0 and 1.1 are not binary- and API-compatible. As of Qt 5.12 (certainly 5.12.4) version 1.1 seems the default OpenSSL backend in Qt, although I hear it can be configured to keep using 1.0.
I'm testing this source for Windows OpenSSL 1.1 builds, no problems so far: https://bintray.com/vszakats/generic/openssl

Comment: Where do you find libssl32.dll under this link? The other two seem to be there but libssl32.dll is missing.

Comment: @DamirPorobic: don't know what's that, I only ever needed the two libraries that are present. In fact, I ran a search across my whole disk C: and there is not a single `libssl32.dll` found, so it doesn't seem I have any software installed that requires it. `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` is all Qt Network needs.

Comment: Came today to the same conclusion. Had libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll all over the place and only using those two seems to fix the issue.